# How Can I Resolve a RequireJS Alias in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, knockoutjs

From a [Disqus comment on my website](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_knockoutjs_integration#comment-2741883568)

> When I look at this file: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml
>
> I see something like this

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
".product-info-main": {
"addToCart": {
"origin": "tier",
"addToCartButton": "#product_addtocart_form [type=submit]",
"inputQty": "#qty",
"attr": "[data-tier-price]",
"productForm": "#product_addtocart_form",
"productId": "",
"productIdInput": "input[type=hidden][name=product]",
"isSaleable": ""
}
}
}
</script>
```

> The "addToCart" should be some javascript file according to this article, but it is not. Maybe this is another feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `addToCart` key **is** a RequireJS module.  However, it's a module that's been aliased with a RequireJS feature -- most likely `map`.  You'll want to [get familiar with the RequireJS integration](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs) in Magento if you plan on doing anything more than tinker with the front end code.

The easiest way I've found to resolve these aliases is some unix `find` combined with `grep`.  The mapping is configured in the `requirejs-config.js` files, so you can find all these files with

```
find vendor/magento/ -name requirejs-config.js
```

If you combine that with the `-exec` feature of find, you can search all these files for the string `addToCart`

```
find vendor/magento/ -name requirejs-config.js -exec grep addToCart '{}' +
```

If you run that command, you'll get the following output

```
vendor/magento//module-msrp/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js:            addToCart: 'Magento_Msrp/js/msrp'
```

If you look in the file

```
/* vendor/magento//module-msrp/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js */
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            addToCart: 'Magento_Msrp/js/msrp'
        }
    }
};
```

You'll see that `addToCart` is aliased to the RequireJS module `Magento_Msrp/js/msrp`.  Without getting into [how Magento serves front end files](http://alanstorm.com/magento-2-frontend-files-serving), that `Magento_Msrp/js/msrp` module will resolve to the file

```
vendor/magento//module-msrp/view/base/web/js/msrp.js
```

While technique won't deterministically zero in on your file every time, I've found it works 99% of the time.